# What is the proper way to use QEMU's socket feature?

Tags: qemu, sockets, transfer

I can't seem to find much documentation anywhere on using the `-serial unix:/path/to/some/file` argument to `qemu-system-XXXX`, so I'm hoping someone here can shed some light on this. Specifically, I'm wondering what the proper way to send data to this socket on the host and receive it on the QEMU guest side.

**Update:** <s>As a test, I'm using a RHEL 8 host and a Solaris 8 guest. As suggested by LawrenceC, I've added the `-serial udp::xxxx` argument. I've also written a C program to connect to UDP port XXXX and write something to it. However, I'm not seeing the written bytes on the RHEL 8 side through `nc -u -l -p xxx`. What might I be missing?</s>

It appears I've had a fundamental misunderstanding of this approach, thinking that a port would open on the QEMU guest, but this simply translates serial port data from the guest to a local UDP port on the host.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to use the virtual serial port interactively with a terminal program?  If so, `minicom` appears to be able to let you interact with a socket instead of a serial port device.  From https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/minicom.1.html:

> ```
>   Serial port setup
> ```

```
     A - Serial device
          /dev/tty1 or /dev/ttyS1 for most people.  [...]
          To use a UNIX socket for communication the device name
          must be prefixed with "unix#" following by the full path
          and the filename of the socket.  Minicom will then try to
          connect to this socket as a client. As long as it cannot
          connect to the socket it stays 'offline'. As soon as the
          connection establishes, minicom goes 'online'. If the
          server closes the socket, minicom switches to 'offline'
          again.
```

If you're trying to use a program to send data to the virtual serial port, try the udp option, and then you can use netcat.

> If you just want a simple readonly console you can use netcat or nc, by starting QEMU with: `-serial udp::4555` and `nc` as: `nc -u -l -p 4555`. Any time QEMU writes something to that port it will appear in the netconsole session.

If you absolutely need to have QEMU's virtual serial port junctioned to a unix socket, try `socat` as recommended [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/187134/is-there-a-netcat-like-utility-that-uses-unix-sockets).

Comment: Ah; I've had a fundamental misunderstanding of things. In this case, QEMU has a serial port, and sending data to that translates into sending things to a local port on the host...

Comment: Update: this approach seems to work well for sending data from QEMU to host.

Answer (score 2):

The [QEmu-KVM notes](https://fishilico.github.io/generic-config/sysadmin/qemu.html#qemu-kvm-notes)
contains this section
[Interaction based on Unix sockets](https://fishilico.github.io/generic-config/sysadmin/qemu.html#interaction-based-on-unix-sockets)
that resumes all the options for using sockets :

> **Interaction based on Unix sockets**
>
> QEmu virtual machines are usually used either in graphical mode, with
> a QEmu windown, or in console mode (-nographic option), with a serial
> console redirected to the standard input/output. A third alternative
> consists in using Unix sockets to communicate with the guest. This can
> be achieved with two QEmu options:
>
> ```
> -monitor unix:monitor.sock,server,nowait
> -serial unix:console.sock,server,nowait
> ```
>
> If the guest machine runs Linux, the virtual serial port will be
> available through device ttyS0. It can be used as a console with early
> kernel messages with these kernel command line parameters:
>
> ```
> console=ttyS0,38400n8 earlyprint=serial,ttyS0,38400n8
> ```
>
> If the guest machine runs systemd, it is possible to automatically
> spawn a login shell on the serial port with the following command:
>
> ```
> systemctl enable serial-getty@ttyS0.service
> ```
>
> Then it is possible to:
>
> - connect to QEmu monitor console for example with:
>
>   ```
>   # Use cfmakeraw to make TAB work and isig=1 to allow using Ctrl+C
>   socat STDIO,cfmakeraw,isig=1 UNIX:monitor.sock
>
>   # socat<1.7.3.0 does not support cfmakeraw. Use raw instead
>   socat STDIO,raw,echo=0,isig=1 UNIX:monitor.sock
>   ```
> - connect to QEmu guest console for example with:
>
>   ```
>   socat STDIO,cfmakeraw UNIX:console.sock
>
>   # or, with socat<1.7.3.0
>   socat STDIO,raw,echo=0 UNIX:console.sock
>   ```